# Is there any more Cocoa component library like BWToolkit?

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I just downloaded and used [BWToolkit](http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/) and quietly impressed.
Nice feature, easy-to-use, stability...

Any other recommendable Cocoa library like this? (not only for UI) Please introduce!

Answer (score 1):

[RegExKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) is a great Objective-C interface to ICU Regular Expressions. I always just use RegExKitLite.